# Weird behavior from either TcpClient or network

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient

So I have two smartbulbs from Yeelight. I am trying to turn them on/off at the same time. You can achieve that by sending some TCP messages to them.
This works completely fine from NodeJS with this little script:

```
const net = require("net")

send_to_lamp("192.168.178.83", '{"id": 1, "method": "set_power", "params": ["on", "sudden"]}\r\n', answ => console.log(answ))
send_to_lamp("192.168.178.84", '{"id": 1, "method": "set_power", "params": ["on", "sudden"]}\r\n', answ => console.log(answ))
console.log("sent")

function send_to_lamp(ip, body, callback) {
    var con = net.createConnection({port: 55443, host: ip}, () => {
            con.write(`asd\r\n`) // send two requests to wake up connection
            con.write(body)
    })
}
```

But now comes the weird behavior to play: When trying to do the exact same thing from C#,
only the first bulb that is contacted reacts to the message. For example when executing this code:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

Thread t1 = new Thread(con1);
t1.Start();
await Task.Delay(1000);
Thread t2 = new Thread(con2);
t2.Start();
await Task.Delay(5000);

async static void con1() {
    await TryConnect("192.168.178.83", "{\"id\": 1, \"method\": \"set_power\", \"params\": [\"on\", \"sudden\"]}\r\n");
}

async static void con2() {
    await TryConnect("192.168.178.84", "{\"id\": 1, \"method\": \"set_power\", \"params\": [\"on\", \"sudden\"]}\r\n");
}

static async Task TryConnect(String server, String message)
{
  try
  {
    using (var client = new TcpClient()){
        await client.ConnectAsync(server, 55443);
        using (var netstream = client.GetStream()) 
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(netstream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(netstream))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            netstream.ReadTimeout = 3000;
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine("sent {0}", message);
        }
    }
  }
  catch (ArgumentNullException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
  }
  catch (SocketException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
  }
}
```

Only the lamp with the IP 192.168.178.83 turns itself on.
It even gets weirder. When just swapping the IP in the both con1/2 functions, so that the lamp with the IP 192.168.178.84 is called first, only it reacts and the lamp with the IP 192.168.178.83 does nothing.
I tried several different methods of sending TCP messages from C# (using async, multi-threading, have a dedicated class for each TcpClient ...)

Anyone got an idea what I can try to get this to work?

[Wireshark log during NodeJS script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roNpj.png)

[Wireshark log during C# script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnRcK.png)

Disclaimer: I do not know much about TCP connections and how they should look in Wireshark, but just seen from the software side of things this really seams nonsensical.

Comment: Your threads terminate before your `TryConnect` returns. `TryConnect` is already a Task, you don't need a `new Thread` to run two in parallel.

Comment: But the Console.WriteLine at the end gets executed. I guess all the "Task" and "new Thread" stuff is just an artifact of me trying different stuff with threads and async. I also tried the synchronous code example from Microsofts TcpClient documentation site, same behavior.

Comment: Try removing the `new Thread` and the `new StreamReader`, and specifying the encoding for the `StreamWriter` (the one that the bulbs expect).

Comment: I removed the ```new Thread``` and set the encoding to ASCII, still same behavior. The requests by themselfs to work if executed from single files, but only one of the two does, if they are executed from the same cs file/process, that is exactly the weird part of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the C # log you have RST because there you are using using which automatically closes the TCP connection. In Node.js, you would probably have to trigger the connection to close manually.

It's best to test your application using a TCP terminal (https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility). Use it to create a local TCP server with listening port 55443.

[Example settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY9eM.png)

Now in your C # application refer both to IP 127.0.0.1 and change the transmitted content to distinguish between frames. For example, for the second lamp, set "id": 2.

This way you will see if your application is establishing a connection correctly and if the transferred data is complete.

Comment: Already tested it with netcat on two different machines but same port (more similar to my usecase) and it worked. But I'm still wondering why always just one of the functions `con1` and `con2` works, but the other one (always the one that is executed second) doesn't when trying to reach the lamps.
Edit: In the C# log the RST got sent on the connection that worked and triggered the lamp as it should